# Pass value to next view when label in Table view cell is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

would love to pass the value postArray[indexpath.row].creatorId when the label inside a tableview cell is tapped so it can be passed onto the next view controller so i can load the profile of that particular creator/user. I used custom cells, so how do i get the creator id based on the location of the label(username) selected.

```
//custom cell
class PostCell : UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var timeAgoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var captionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postStatsLabel: UILabel!

}  

 //do something when label is tapped
    @objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) { 
       //userClicked = creatorData
        print(userClicked)            
        appDelegate.profileView()    
        print("tap working")
    }

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
    if section == 0{
        return 1
    }else{
        return postsArray.count
    }     
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //var returnCell: UITableViewCell! 

    if indexPath.section == 0 {          
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "statusCell", for: indexPath) as! statusCell
        profilePicture = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userPic") as? String
        if profilePicture != nil {
            //load profile picture from library
            let urlString = "https://test.com/uploads/profile-picture/"+(profilePicture)!
            let profileURL = URL(string: urlString)
            cell.statusProfilePic?.downloadedFrom(url: profileURL!)
            } else {
            print("you have no profile picture set")
        }          
        return cell  
    } else {

        if postsArray[indexPath.row].photos != nil{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell  

            if postsArray[indexPath.row].comments != nil {
                comments = postsArray[indexPath.row].comments?.count
            } else {
                comments = 0
            }

            if postsArray[indexPath.row].like_list != nil {
                likes = postsArray[indexPath.row].like_list?.count
            }else{

                likes = 0
            }
            //assign post id to PostID
            postID = postsArray[indexPath.row].post_id
            //make username clickable!
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NewsfeedTableViewController.tapFunction))
            cell.usernameLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.usernameLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            cell.usernameLabel.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].fullname
            cell.timeAgoLabel.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].data_created
            cell.captionLabel.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].content
            cell.timeAgoLabel.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].modified
            //15 Likes     30 Comments     500 Shares
            cell.postStatsLabel.text = "\(likes!) Likes      \(comments!)  Comments"
            //load profile picture from library
            let urlString = "https://test.com/uploads/profile-picture/"+(postsArray[indexPath.row].profile_pic_filename)!
            let profileURL = URL(string: urlString)
            cell.profileImageView.downloadedFrom(url: profileURL!)
            //iterate through posts images images array
            //load post picture from server library
            var postImageName : String?

            if postsArray[indexPath.row].photos != nil{
                let postImage = postsArray[indexPath.row].photos
                for postsImage in postImage!{
                    postImageName = postsImage.filename!
                }
                let urlPostImageString = "https://test.com/uploads/post-picture/"+(postImageName)!
                let postsImageUrl = URL(string: urlPostImageString)
                cell.postImageView.downloadedFrom(url: postsImageUrl!)
            } else {
                print("Post has no picture")
            }
            //return cell
            return cell
        } else {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NoImageCell", for: indexPath) as! NoImageTableViewCell

            if postsArray[indexPath.row].comments != nil {
                comments = postsArray[indexPath.row].comments?.count
            } else {
                comments = 0
            }

            if postsArray[indexPath.row].like_list != nil {
                likes = postsArray[indexPath.row].like_list?.count
            } else {
             likes = 0
            }

            //make username clickable!
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NewsfeedTableViewController.tapFunction))
            cell.noImageUsername.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.noImageUsername.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            cell.noImageUsername.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].fullname
            cell.noImageTime.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].data_created
            cell.noImagePost.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].content
            cell.noImageTime.text = postsArray[indexPath.row].modified

            //15 Likes     30 Comments     500 Shares
            cell.noImageLikeAndComment.text = "\(likes!) Likes      \(comments!)  Comments"
            //load profile picture from library
            let urlString = "https://test.com/uploads/profile-picture/"+(postsArray[indexPath.row].profile_pic_filename)!
            let profileURL = URL(string: urlString)
            cell.noImageProfilePic.downloadedFrom(url: profileURL!)
            return cell
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: Should your cell do anything else when tapped? Or would tapping anywhere in the view elicit that response

Comment: @Jake yes the cell will segue to a diff view when tapped, that view will be for commenting and viewing comments. right now i'm working on getting the creator id so i can display the profile of the creator of the post.

Comment: Ok, just so I understand. Tapping the cell should do one thing and tapping the label in the cell should do another.

Comment: Yes @Jake , hope it makes sense! i already got the label to segue to the profile VC but still can't get the creator id

Answer (score 0):

Use this for example.
Implement didSelectRow() method and in it write something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // this method works, when you taped cell. write here code of you need. Next code only example, which set user info to some VC and push it:
        let controller =  UserController as? UserController
        if let controller = controller {
            controller.user = users[indexPath.row]
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

add this to your Cell's class:

```
func setTap() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapRecognized))
        self.label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    }

    @objc func tapRecognized(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // here your code of tap on label
        print("label tapped")
    }
```

Check on storyBoard is your label isUserInteractionEnabled? - set it to true. Inside tapRecodnized() method do what are you need. And you need to call method setTap() in your cell's method, which you call in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.

**Update**

Simple example. this code know what are you tapped. if you tap cell, but not label, add code of push some controller, else code of push another controller.
Cell's Class:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var mainController: ViewController?

    func setText(text: String) {
        setTap()
        label.text = text
    }

    func setTap() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapRecognized))
        self.label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    }

    @objc func tapRecognized(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let mainController = mainController {
            print("label tapped")
            mainController.pushSomeVc(cell: self)
        }

    }
}
```

Code of main Class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func pushSomeVc(cell: MyTableViewCell) {
        let row = myTableView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row
        if let row = row {
            // write here code of push controller, when label tapped. row property for get some user from array
            print("push some vc with \(row)")
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? MyTableViewCell
        if let cell = cell {
            cell.setText(text: array[indexPath.row])
            cell.mainController = self
        }
        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        // write here code of push controller with comments
        print("cell tapped: \(indexPath.row)")
    }

}
```

I tested this code and it's work perfect

Comment: HI Sergey, what does UserController stand for? is that the view controller with the table? or the view controller i intend to pass the value to?

Comment: it will be view controller you intend to pass the value to.

Comment: `it will be view controller you intend to pass the value to` - yes. I don't know what are you need, it's example. if you need to show some controller with user info, use it according this scheme.

Comment: "Ok, just so I understand. Tapping the cell should do one thing and tapping the label in the cell should do another"
Please remember this...that's why i can't do a didselectedRow
It's tapping the label that i'm interested in right now. how do i get the creatorId when the label(username) is tapped?

Comment: @SanfordSmithers You would need to make the label tappable. By default, it isn't. Or use a button instead of a label. Buttons are tappable.

Comment: Then you simply work out which row of the table the tapped label / button is in, and take it from there. You know the index path, thus you can look up the info in your `postArray`.

Comment: i've already made the label tappable! problem is i don't know how to figure out which row of the table has been tapped

Comment: It's trivial. In your `tapFunction` the `sender` is the tap gesture recognizer. The gesture recognizer's `view` is the label. The label's superview is the cell's `contentView`. The content view's superview is the cell. Now ask the table what the index path is for that cell. Done.

Comment: you can create property like currentRow = indexPath.row and your problem can be solved

Comment: okay. if you tap on label - you will show some controller with info about user, and when you tap cell, but not label, what will happen?

Comment: If i tap on cell but not label, it will show another view controller that allows user to Post a comment or read comments about the post(cell) he has tapped. The label has the username of the person making the post, so in order to load the profile of that person i need to get his creatorId

Comment: Hey mate, thank you for the brilliant effort! i really appreciate it. Allow me some time to try this out on my end then get back to you! Thank You